# Конвертирование объекта одного класса в другой

Tags: c++

Не подскажите как реализовать конвертирование одного класса в другой?
Например, есть у меня классы:

```
class A
{
public:
    int *a;
}
```

и

```
class S
{
public:
   std::string *s;
}
```

и я создал 2 объекта:

```
A tmp1;
S tmp2;
tmp1 = (mp_it1)tmp2;
tmp1 != tmp2;
```

Я предполагаю, что мне нужно, что то вроде 
`operator А() const {  }` в классе `S` и подобное в классе `А`. Но как мне так же передать переменные класса не представляю.

Как мне реализовать такое перетиповывание? Очень желательно с примером.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае преобразование любого класса `A` в другой класс `B` может быть реализовано тремя способами:

1. В класс `B` добавить конструктор, принимающий аргумент типа `A` или любого другого типа, в который `A` может быть преобразован неявно:

   ```
   struct B {
       B(const A& a) {/* формируем новый объект типа B из переменной `a` */} 
   };
   ```
2. В класс `A` добавить оператор преобразования в `B`:

   ```
   struct A {
       operator B() const {/* формируем новый объект типа B из this и возвращаем */}
   };
   ```
3. Реализовать фунцию преобразования, т.е. любую функцию, принимающую `A` (или любой другой тип, в который может быть неявно преобразован `A`) и возвращающую `B`:

   ```
   B f(const A& a) {/* формируем новый объект типа B из переменной `a` и возвращаем */}
   ```

Какой из вариантов выбрать, зависит от ситуации:

- Если класс `B` допускает модификацию, то следует выбрать первый
  вариант, как наиболее очевидный с точки зрения языка (за создание
  объекта отвечает конструктор).
- Если класс `B` не допускает
  модификацию (или вовсе не является классом, например, это может быть
  просто `int`), а класс `A` допускает, то используем второй вариант.
- Если нельзя изменить ни `A`, ни `B`, то используем третий вариант.

Первые два варианта могут быть использованы для неявного преобразования типов (если не указано ключевое слово `explicit`). Третий вариант будет требовать явного вызова функции преобразования.

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось проще чем я думал:

```
operator А() const { return А(); }
```

В обоих классах должны быть конструкторы, «знающие» как работать с переменными других классов.

Например в А:

```
A::A(std::string s)
{
    //тут преобразуем в int
}
```